# Issue with logging not working correctly when using retries in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a use case where I'm testing something on our network, and sometimes the network takes a little longer than usual and the test ends up checking too early. Ideally, I would be able to set the test to retry with this.retries(1). When I do that, it does indeed retry and it works; however, it breaks my logging. I'm running a lot of tests, and if I don't use the retry function the logging for each suite gets split appropriately. But if a test gets retried, it stops splitting up the logs and they all get located under one test suite. I have no idea why and haven't been able to find any similar reports. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrying you can also try [timeouts](http://mochajs.org/#timeouts) because it is made for this.

This may resolve your issue as timeouts simply make mocha wait more time before setting the test as failed so it doesn't change the logs.

Comment: I am using timeouts, but sometimes the set timeout isn't long enough. It would be much easier to simply retry one test rather than set a longer timeout for every test.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the error has something to do with combining setTimeout and a retry. Something to do with it not getting to done() on an error.